# Bootstrap Panel is not collapsing in mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap

The panel is dropping down just fine but is not collapsing back. I am using the latest version of jquery and bootstrap.

```
var i = 1;
    foreach (QuestionModelClass t in Model.QuestionPagedList)
    {
        if (t.QuestionTitle != null)
        {
            <div class="panel-group" id="accordion_@i">
                <div class="panel panel-success" id="panel_@i">

                    @*panel header*@
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h4 class="panel-title">
                            @i<span>.</span>
                            <a data-toggle="collapse" href="#collapseOne_@i" style="text-decoration: none;">
                                <strong>@t.QuestionTitle</strong>
                                <span class="pull-right badge">@t.LangName</span>
                            </a>
                        </h4>
                    </div>

                    @*Collapsable panel Body*@
                    <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapseOne_@i">
                        <div class="panel-body">
                            @t.QuestionDesc
                            <br>
                            <strong>Posted by</strong> : @t.name
                            <br><br>
                            @Html.ActionLink("View or Answer the question", "Solution", new { qID = t.QuestionId })
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        }
        i++;
```

I tried `for loop` instead of `foreach` but still it doesn't work.

Comment: where is the javascript code?

Comment: i am using the `bootstrap.min.js` and `jquery-3.2.1.min.js` which was already present in the project folder